# Why does android.util.Base64 return a different string?

Tags: java, android, base64

I'm using android.util.Base64 to encode a username + password for HTTP Basic Authentication like so:

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

If I used "user" & "pass" for the username and password I would expect to get dXNlcjpwYXNzCg== (from openssl)

```
echo 'user:pass' | openssl base64
```

but instead I get this:

[image: returned string]

Any ideas why this is?

Thanks,

Jake

Note: Simply passing the resulting string to a show progress dialog:

```
Tools.ShowProgress(encoded, Login.this);
```

Comment: Remember that `echo` prints a `\n` character at the end of the line. avoid this with the `-n` option: `echo -n "user:pass" | openssl base64`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(username+":"+password).getBytes()
```

[String.getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) returns the bytes of the string in the current platform encoding. To ensure you match other platforms, you probably want to use [String.getBytes(Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) with UTF-8:

```
(username+":"+password).getBytes("UTF-8")
```

If that's not the issue, another thing to check is if your input is what you think it is:

```
String input = username+":"+password;
log.warn("Input was: " + input);
// calculate base64
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I missed out a getText() on one of my inputs instead of username.getText().toString() I had username.toString()